# Print HTML page with CSS background shades/images

Tags: html, css

I have an online ticket booking system, the customer can print the tickets directly from the webpage using print command of browser.

However I am facing a problem that the background shades/images using css backround does not appear on the hard copy of tickets, though it's displaying perfectly on the web page. Ok I can use  tags but what about the backround shades and watermark images?

Thanks! in advance...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is often an issue with the browser itself. Some browsers such as IE 8 will not print backgrounds by default, and must have the option turned on.

See [How to print webpage with background image?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5064904/how-to-print-webpage-with-background-image) for more information.

There are some workarounds, such as actually using images instead of backgrounds, but generally they are not pretty.

Comment: Yup — if you want to maximise control over the printed output (which, with tickets, I assume you would), then you’d probably be better off providing the whole ticket as an image, or preferably in a more print-oriented document format like PDF.

Comment: Thanks! I must better convert the page in pdf first. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can either try to define rules in a print.css file (which would have media set to "print", not "screen" like your regular css fule). Or, you can use a tool for converting the page to pdf and then print it. If you go in that direction, I suggest looking into wkhtmltopdf. It's pretty straight-forward to implement.