# Printing a Page - images don't print, only the text works

Tags: html, css, button, printing

I am working on a page for order confirmation.  There is a button to print the page.  When I print, only the text on the page works.  None of the images (there are 3 images) show up when I print.  Only white space where there should have been an image.

code for print button on the phtml page

```
    <span class="pay-invoice" onClick="window.print();return false">
        <a class="ssPortalPg_print_icon"></a>
        Print This Page
    </span>
```

css of pay-invoice

```
.pay-invoice {
    float: right;
}

.pay-invoice:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
    opacity: 0.6;
}
```

css of ssPortalPg_print_icon

```
.ssPortalPg_print_icon {
    float: left;
    height: 13px;
    width: 13px;
    display: block;
    background: url(../images/ssPortalPg_print_icon.png) no-repeat;
    margin-top: 9px;
    margin-right: 3px;
}
```

image of the print button on the right
[image]

Comment: possible duplicate of [Print webpage with background images and colors?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1038605/print-webpage-with-background-images-and-colors)

Comment: Background images /colors don't print by default. You will need to enable them...and that's not easy.

Comment: Yes.  That's what I am trying to figure out.  There was another page similar to this that had the code only for Chrome, but there is nothing I see currently for either IE or Firefox.