# how to set background image in print page(template) in django

Tags: html, css, django, django-templates

#### CSS:

```
table.print{
    width:123px;
    height:298px;
    background-position:center;
    background:url('{{ STATIC_URL }}images/human.png'); 
}
```

#### HTML:

```
<table id="human-body" class="print" >
    <tr>
        <td>some data</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

The above HTML is used as a print template in django in my app. My problem is, I used the above CSS to apply the background image to the print page. But if I press print button and see the print preview the background image is missing. I checked with printing it in paper also,the image is missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are looking to print background image,then follow the below steps

1.To enable background printing in Chrome and Safari web browsers add

```
-webkit-print-color-adjust:exact;
```

in your print.css file,rest all is same

2.In FireFox by default `"Print Background colours and images"` turned off in their print settings,`no CSS will override that.`

User should manually turn on if background image is required.

Steps for turn on background in FF:

```
Go to File -->Page setup -->Formats & Options -->Tick Print background(images & colors)
```

Comment: Late answer,I solved it also refer this thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11242991/how-to-forcefully-print-background-image-in-html

Answer (score 0):

You can't use STATIC_URL in css files. You can only use it in template.

Comment: In css how to set the image url,i am using django

Comment: Just write full link:
`background:url('../images/human.png');`

Comment: This way also i tried,but the background image for table is not applied.