# Repeating css image as content

Tags: html, css, asp.net

I need to have an image *repeat* and be visible both on the screen and while printing. So far using

```
body {
    background:url(images/confidential.png) repeat;
}

@media Print {
    body:before { 
         content: url(images/confidential.png);
         position: absolute;
         z-index: -1;
    }
}
```

works with the exception of the repeat when printing. Suggestions? Thanks.

Comment: Most browsers ignore the background when printing, so in this case only the content from the body::before is used. This is a browser setting, not a problem with your css.

Comment: @MrLister That's the point of this css. I need to get the content to repeat.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11242991/how-to-forcefully-print-background-image-in-html - this post may help you

Comment: @Shawn You don't understand; this is a *browser* issue. Meaning you can't control it with CSS.

Comment: @TylerH I'm not sure how this is a browser issue as this code currently prints the image just fine, regardless of browser settings. The only thing I need is some way to get the image to repeat.

Comment: Have you considered adding a repeated image (very large image, multiplying the original image a few times) in your print speficic css?

Comment: @JoostS Good idea, any way I can make it clip as if it was a normal background image?

Comment: Thanks. Maybe CSS clip rect?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Most browsers' default behavior is not printing the background colors.
But `image`, `SVG` and property `content` does it well.

Use SVG solution(fill pattern) to achieve like the repeating image background:

https://jsfiddle.net/k459wv6w/

```
<svg height="0" width="0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1"> 
  <defs> 
    <pattern id="rainbow" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse" width="300" height="300"> 
      <image xlink:href="http://www.fnordware.com/superpng/pnggrad8rgb.png" 
        x="0" y="0" width="300" height="300">
      </image> 
    </pattern> 
  </defs> 
</svg>
<svg height="100%" width="100%" style="float:left" class="pattern-swatch">
  <rect style="fill: url(#rainbow) #fff;" x="0" y="0" height="100%" width="100%"></rect>
</svg>
```

Comment: This seems promising. How do I move it to the background? It does not look like SVG has Z-indexes?

Comment: To clarify, I have a table that I'd like this to fill.

Comment: @Shawn `svg` element can use z-axis, but inside it can't. It's 2d canvas don't have z-axis. sample: https://jsfiddle.net/k459wv6w/3/

Comment: It'd be perfect if it only filled the table, but I can live with this. Thanks for your help fixing this _browser_ problem.

Comment: @Shawn sorry really don't know what you mean at first. you can use `position: absolute` to achieve your goal. Glad to help you :D

Answer (score 1):

I am not so sure if this could be an option to you. But even if you try to force the printing settings via CSS, different browsers can have different setting being switched on and off, [Check link for more info](http://its.yale.edu/how-to/article-printing-web-page-background-colors-and-images), therefore you have an option to explicitly put the background image in `<img>` tag and style it as following:

```
.background {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  background: transparent url("http://www.fnordware.com/superpng/pnggrad8rgb.png") repeat scroll 0% 0%;
  //background-repeat: repeat-x;
}
```

I have created [JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/yb09y9jz/1/) to demo this