# How can I get a default background graphics when I click (Ctrl + p) to print anything on browser?

Tags: html, css, angular, google-chrome, printing

[I want by default background graphics to be added when someone prints anything on browser.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GatVI.png)

Comment: Media queries. You can add CSS to `print` only. just add `@media print { background-image: url('myimage.jpg'); }`

Comment: [duplicate] https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11242991/how-to-forcefully-print-background-image-in-html

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.