# how to print background image?

Tags: css, image

when i click print option background image is not printing..could u please help me out.
here is my css

```
.OldNote {  
    background-image: url(/images/icons/arkiv.gif);
    background-repeat: repeat;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0px;
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I print background images in FF or IE?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/596876/how-can-i-print-background-images-in-ff-or-ie)

Answer (score 3):

Usually it is up to the user and their browser settings to print or not print background images. Check your browser settings.

If you don't want to rely on that, don't place the image in the background, place it on your page in an `<img>`-tag.

Comment: Hi Bjoern,,i tried using browser setting but no luck..if i place <img> tag in my page how can i give css to that img to repeat image in background?

Comment: Foreground images cannot be repeated via css, only background images can.

Comment: anyway thanks for ur answer..i solved it by changing the media="screen" to media="all".

Answer (score 0):

You can just add an image tag like this, whereever you want the image to be displayed :

```
 <img src="url" class='printableonly' />
```

Then in the css, you can do like this :

```
  @media screen {
      .printableonly{
           display: none;
       }
  }

  @media print{
     .printableonly {

          display: inline;

       }
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

i just add, if you want it to be background, there is no know way to make it repeat like a common backgrond. To put it under the content you may use css as adding it in other element before the content and giving both elements css  **position: absolute** style, together with the **z-index: .. **, where z-index of content will be bigger.

Maybe you may look into full size background solution which is made very similar