# CSS being ignored in Print view

Tags: css, html

I have been trying to create an exact view of my `HTML` form when i strike `ctrl+p` but my `CSS` is being ignored in a print view and all the styling i did for `textfields`, `radio button`s etc they are not being displayed and by default styling is being displayed in the print view. 
Following is my page where I want to apply the same print view the way the form really is

Kindly let me know how can I do that.

[**My Page**](http://caremerge.us/rai_form/form1.html)

**Note:** I tried to `media="all"` on my attached stylesheet and also created another css file for print view (The css file is same i used for the styling of my form) print.css and include that file by

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/print.css" type="text/css" media="print"  charset="utf-8" />
```

`
But it also did not worked and after doing this in print view my customized form elements does not appear.

Comment: Try removing the `media` attribute.

Comment: Did you refresh your cache after you changed the `media` attribute to `all`?

Comment: @AndresIlich yes, i did that and nothing happened

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using background images to style the form inputs, but non current browser does print any background images. This is not a bug but a feature to save toner ink.

See also [How can I print background images in FF or IE?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/596876/how-can-i-print-background-images-in-ff-or-ie) ans similar questions.

Comment: @Mr. Alien I used the code inspector in Chromium. No need to know the source URL for the CSS file.

Comment: He has not even linked the stylesheet on the page he's pointing to hehe.. View source and check yourself..

Comment: @Mr.Alien i have uploaded that stylesheet now kindly see if you can help all i want that images i used for form elements should be displayed in print view. KIndly visit this url http://caremerge.us/rai_form/form1.html

Comment: @softgenic Did you read feeela's answer? Or else if you want to see the layout correctly use `media="screen"` and link another as `media="print"` or click on page setup and click on `print background(colors and images)`

Comment: @Mr. Alien `print background(colors and images)` Which browser does have such an option? I don't see it in Opera, Firefox or Chromium. Also teh stylesheet was correctly linked – otherwise the forms weren't styled…

Comment: @feeela Go to File -> Page Setup and see there will be such option

Comment: @feeela Am using w7 I guess your menu bar is off, press alt, click on file and select page setup btw am using firefox 10.2

Answer (score -3):

Use html5.js it will help for web print. As print will not proper as for design expertise. http://paulirish.com/2011/the-history-of-the-html5-shiv/ or https://github.com/aFarkas/html5shiv