# IE Not printing Properly

Tags: css, internet-explorer, printing

is anyone knows why is IE (8,9 Tested) 
refuse to print the right side of this coupon? (on the Red Background)
the left side (phone number) is printed ok.

other browsers (chrome, FF) print whole doc ok.

http://www.weekend.co.il/templatesfiles/coupons/coupon.aspx?id=20483%20&resttype=19&coupontype=2

to see the Bug you can just print to file / or left click >> Print Preview..

Thanks!

Arik

Answer (score 1, accepted):

found it !
need to specifiy the Background image as follow:

```
 .background 
 {   
  display: list-item;   
  list-style-image: url(yourbackgroundimage.gif);   
  list-style-position: inside; 
 }
```

Thanks DahlinDev
https://stackoverflow.com/a/1218059/422827

Answer (score 2):

IE is not set to print background images by default.

```
Goto Print Preview
Click the gears icon.
Tick the box - Print Background Colors and Images.
```

[image]

**Here is my printing attempt.**

[image]

Comment: thanks, i've been there already.. set the backgroung images in the internet option as describe here
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/296326
no change.

Comment: I have tried this and it works for me. Sorry i cant be more help.

Comment: thanks you right, it does print ok.
is this the only option ?
i can't force my users to go all this way to print..
and i do want the red (and rounded) background..

why is the Phone number (left side) printing ok without the trick?

Comment: Nope, IE has done this from day zero AFAIK. Perhaps look up other ways to get your stuff to print. Google it.